# Angular filters doesn't work if $compile service

Tags: jquery, angularjs, single-page-application

I can't seem to figure out why the **orderBy** filter  isn't working on $complie elements.

i am modifying element at  the run time after that i am using $compile service to manually compile the modified element in order to work angular directive properly,but i have notice one things after applying $compile service my order by filter is not working properly.

```
 <table class="gridTable" id="serviceContractTable" flexicolumns="srcCustomer.ServiceContracts:500"  pagesize="10">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <th sorting="ContractRefNo">Contract Ref No</th>
      <th class="rightAlign" sorting="PaymentInterval">Payment Interval</th>

      <th class="centreAlign">
        <a class="src-plus-2" style="text-transform: none;" ng-click="loadSvcContract()">&nbsp;ADD</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="serviceContractBody">
    <tr ng-hide="contract.Deleted" ng-repeat="contract in srcCustomer.ServiceContracts | orderBy:serviceContractTable:reverseserviceContractTable" class="tableRow" ng-click="loadSvcContract(contract)">
      <td>{{contract.ContractRefNo}}</td>
      <td class="rightAlign">{{contract.PaymentInterval}}</td>
      <td class="centreAlign"><span dateformat ng-model="contract.StartDate"></span></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my table element on which i have apply directive as flexicolumns and in that i have inject one service which use $compile.

//directive

```
myApp.directive('flexicolumns', ['$http','InfiniteScroll', 'FlexiColumns', function (http, infiniteScroll, flexiColumns) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(scopeElement, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                scope.isTableLoaded = false;
                if (newValue != undefined) {
                    if (newValue.length > 0) {
                       flexiColumns.FlexiColumn(element,scope, {
                                    height: tblHeight
                       });
```

//service

```
    myApp.factory('FlexiColumns', function ($compile) {

return {

        FlexiColumn: function (element,scope, agr) {
           // all the code here to modified element 
          // here i am cloning the element
          var newElement = element.clone(true, true);
          $compile($(newElement ).html())(scope); 

    };
    }
```

please let me know where it's going wrong how i can use filter with $compile service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the element returned by the linker funciton. The API for $compile works like this:

```
var newScope = $scope.$new()
newScope.whatever = Math.random();
var linker = $compile("<div>{{5 + 5}} - {{whatever}}</div>");
var element = linker(newScope);
```

So, have FlexiColumn return the JQLite/JQuery object returned by the linker, and put that element into the DOM. Only compiling and linking something that is already in the DOM doesn't work, you have to put the linked element in the DOM yourself.

Comment: let me clear my understanding, means should i apply $compile on element which return from Flexicoulmn service?

Comment: You should return the element you compile+link from the service, since the link fn returns the actual element you want to use.